# Are there any methods to calculate the % of position size to cover my profits based on achieving expected returns and thereafter?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, profitability, price-theory

Perhaps modifying Kelly Criterion to gauge the % of bet size to cover and adjusting to a new expected value? I want to let my profits run without exiting the trade prematurely. (or should I just liquidate once my expected returns have been reached?) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... specifics might help.

Comment: Are you talking about position sizing?

Comment: Yes position sizing, although not for entry but for taking partial profits and letting the remainder of contracts to run. I thought of doing another kelly and taking the difference between the new and original kelly as the amount of contracts to cover upon hitting my expected return.